# Could the exponent be raised on the limit operator instead of the whole expression?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

Could we use
$$\underset{x\to c}{\lim}^nf(x)$$
to denote
$$\big(\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\big)^n$$

Comment: I don't think its a common notation.

Comment: I've only seen this notation on functions. Aside from that, this would be used so rarely I don't it would be beneficial at all.

Comment: Without definition one could confuse it with $\lim^n f =\lim \cdots \lim f$ (which is idempotent).

Comment: What is $n$ supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course *define* it as such, but it is not 'official'. Note that $$(\lim_{x\to c}f(x))^n={\lim_{x\to c}}^n f(x)$$ is a function of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think thats a good idea: $\lim^n$ looks like you apply the linear operator $\lim$ defined on some space of functions with codomain $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty,-\infty\}$ $n$ times, which is not what you want, because you have an actual multiplication $\lim\times \lim \times \dots \times\lim$ in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This expression $$\underset{x\to c}{\lim}^nf(x) $$does not make sense.

On the other hand $$\big(\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\big)^n$$ means you take the limit first and raise the result to the $n^{th}$ power.

Comment: whatever $f^n(x)$ might be ;-) (think about $n=-1$).

Comment: Correct.  $f^n(x)$ should be defined.